# WPF Binding don't update data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

So the problem is that whatever I do changing text in my textbox doesn't change the property in code although I bind it. 
I'm using MVVM pattern so:
My Model:

```
public class Shipment
{
    public Shipment() {}

    public int ShipmentId {get;set;}

    //LP and Payer
    [Required]
    public long ExternalNumber {get ; set;}
    public long MPKNumber { get; set; }
    public long ContractNumber { get; set; }
    public Payer Payer { get; set; }
    public Payment Payment { get; set; }
    //And much more but i'm working on these right now
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
 public class PrepareNewViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    private Shipment shipment { get; set; }

    public Shipment Shipment
    {
        get
        {
            return shipment;
        }
        set
        {
            if (shipment != value)
            {
                shipment = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Shipment");
            }
        }
    } 

    public PrepareNewViewModel()
    {
        Shipment = new Shipment();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And my View:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:Controls ="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit" 
      xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" 
      x:Class="SmartShipping.Views.Pages.PrepeareNew" 
      xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:SmartShipping.ViewModels" 
      xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
      xmlns:Model ="clr-namespace:SmartShipping.Model" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="889" d:DesignWidth="959" 
      Title="PrepeareNew">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:PrepareNewViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Page.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnumPayer" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="Model:Payer"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>

        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnumPayment" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="Model:Payment"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Page.Resources>

    <GroupBox Header="LIST PRZEWOZOWY I PŁATNIK" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,131,0,0" Height="146" Width="458">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="448" Margin="0,0,-2,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="28*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="28*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="56*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Content="Nr zewnętrzny:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,8,0,0" Width="138" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <TextBox Height="24" Margin="10,31,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     Text="{Binding Shipment.ExternalNumber, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

            <Label Content="Nr MPK:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                   Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Column="2" Width="73"/>
            <TextBox Height="24" Margin="0,31,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     Text="{Binding Shipment.MPKNumber, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2" 
                     Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}"/>

            <Label Content="Płatnik usługi:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,69,0,0"/>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnumPayer}}"  
                      Margin="10,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="24" 
                      Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}"/>

            <Label Content="Forma płatności:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,69,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Shipment.Payment}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnumPayment}}" 
                      Margin="10,92,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="24" 
                      Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}" 
                      Grid.Column="1"/>

            <Label Content="Nr umowy:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,66,0,0" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" 
                     Margin="0,92,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214" Grid.Column="2" 
                     Text="{Binding Shipment.ContractNumber, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</Page>
```

Could it be that i don't bind every property of model ?

Comment: Does your Shipment.ExternalNumber public property raise on property changed?

Comment: No, but as you see the whole Shipment property does. I will try to add it and see if it helps

Comment: Turn on advanced tracing and debug.   diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"  It should show any binding errors.

Comment: use http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ to check your DataContext and Binding at runtime

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb for MVVM is that the ViewModel and the View have a 1-to-1 relationship. It would make more sense to me, if you had properties for each member of Shipment. Otherwise, Shipment's members will not be updated. Although intuitively Shipment is technically changing, properties are only updated when you update their value - not their members.

Your textboxes are technically only bound only One way. When you change them, the members of Shipment are not updated. I was curious if this was possible so I tested it myself in a project I am working on and sure enough changing my Model's members didn't proc RaisePropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set datacontext in View.cs. Like this (preferably in the constructor):

```
this.DataContext=shipmentObject;
```